# How to send SIGINT to a Popen() function

Tags: c++

How do I interrupt a process started from C++ with the `popen` call — how do I send it a SIGINT?  Here is the `popen` call:

```
FILE* pipe = popen("vlc", "r");
```

I would like to close `vlc` when I want with an interrupt signal.

Comment: a similar problem has already been adressed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/548063/kill-a-process-started-with-popen

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/548063/kill-a-process-started-with-popen.

Answer (score 0):

Why not implement your own signal handler and do a pclose on the opened pipe?
That should send sigpipe to VLC.
popen is really a bad way to fork the process. you get no PID out of it. There are a lot of implementations floating around that do the same thing using fork and that return also a PID.
Ask back if you can't find any.